# Toggle <li> Background Image

Tags: jquery, css, class, html-lists, background-image

I have a UL with LI items that make up my links. Each link has a class of "linkItem" and either "roomActive" or "roomInactive" to show the appropriate BG image, and an ID that is passed into my function to show which LI item is clicked on.

I am trying to use the following code to accomplish this.

```
$(".roomLink")[id].removeClass('roomActive').addClass('roomInactive');
```

When I run this I get back an error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'removeClass' "

I also tried using the jQuery .css("background") and it returned "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'css' "

Any ideas?

Comment: Is ID the actual ID of the LI?

Comment: If we saw your whole function it would help. I image that you could just use $(this). And should you be removing class 'roomInactive' and adding 'roomActive' on all the other '.roomLink' items?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
$(".roomLink").eq(id).removeClass('roomActive').addClass('roomInactive');
```

**Assuming** `id` is the index of the `li` you want to removeClass and addClass. This assumption is based on the way you have used it. (like index)

You code `$(".roomLink")[id]` is a dom object and it has no `addClass/removeClass` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$($(".roomLink")[id]).removeClass`..... it probably says that because what is returned when you index the array of objects is not a jquery object.

Answer (score 0):

If elements have an id on them then go by the id:

```
$("#" + id).removeClass('roomActive').addClass('roomInactive');
```

but if you bind the click handler directly to the li then you can do:

```
$(".roomLink").click(function(){ 
    $(this).removeClass('roomActive').addClass('roomInactive');
});
```

you can play around with the css like this:

```
$(this).css("background-image","url(imageurl)");
```

you need to pass the css property name and the value as you'd put it in a stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

When you access an element by `[]` you are returning the DOM element, not a jQuery object. Try `eq(id)` instead (assuming id is the index).

If you are trying to toggle classes when another link is clicked, then something like this works well.

```
$('li').click( function() {
    //swap inactive class in for currently active link item
    $('li.active').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
    //add active class to the clicked one
    $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active');
});
```